# Laravel 7 - How to use other table except users table for login?

Tags: php, laravel-7

I face a problem when I want to Laravel default authentication (which is done by php artisan make:auth). For now i am using Laravel 7

i have another table name employee to store user info (username, password, and so on), but so far what I know, Laravel uses 'users' table to store user information.

There is no way to rename user_account to users to solve the issue.

Is there any way to user_account in Laravel so that Laravel uses that table during login, registration, and so on..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a different authentication guard in the config/auth.php file, the new guard needs to use your table.
Then in the model for that table extend the lluminate\Foundation\Auth\User class.
Maybe this help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M

Also your login controller needs to use the custom auth guard.